# What lovely weather they are having! - possible?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know that it's OK to say: "What lovely weather we are having today!" But if we mention the place where we are not present at the moment, can we use 'they' instead of 'we'? Or are there some other possibilities to use this pattern?

Comment: Do you mean something like you being in place X and the people (and the weather) you're referring to being in place Y?

Comment: @eijen Yes, exactly.

Comment: Sure... "What lovely weather they're having [in Hawaii] today!" or "I hear they're having horrid weather [in Alaska] today". The sections in brackets can be omitted if the subject is known already.

Answer (score 1):

As a native American English speaker, I would understand it if you said "What lovely weather they are having in Hawaii today", as mentioned in the comments, but it would not sound natural to me.  Instead I would say something like "The weather is lovely in Hawaii today".

As for the pattern, "what ____ we are having today", I can't think of another place it would be commonly used.